# How did my textbook find the interval of convergence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am reading my text and I understand this theorem:

[image]

and I see this question:

[image]

It looks like they found the interval of convergence, not just the radius. But the theorem only gives us the radius right?

Do they just look at:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-x^7)^n$$

and realize it's geometric and that $r = (-x^7)$?

Is the radius = 0?

Comment: The interval of convergence is always symmetric about $a$ so once you've found the radius, you know the interval.  The first expression you've highlighted shows that.  Is there more to this question that I see?

Comment: The author refers to the properties of the Geometric series, discussed earlier in that book

Comment: Is the right way to think of this is that since it's geometric, $|x^7| < 1$ and so R = 1 since a = 0, the interval is -1 < 0 < 1? Do we have to manually check the endpoints?

Answer (score 1):

No. The $a$ value is $0$ and since you have $-1\lt x\lt 1$ you have $R=1$

Comment: Is another way to think if this is that since it's geometric, you have that $|x^7| < 1$ so $R = 1$?

Comment: Yes. But $|x^7|<1$ implies $|x|<1$